# what is no-ip.com used for?

Tags: security

i see lot of hacking internet security communities mention it.

is it suppose to make you invisible ?

any ideas ?

Answer (score 3):

They are simply a DNS service provider, much like [DynDNS](http://www.dyndns.com/). Their most popular free service allows you to use one of their sub domains and point it to your dynamic IP address. This is useful if you need to frequently access a remote computer over remote desktop for example, as remembering a sub domain is easier than remembering an IP address.

Comment: +1: I've a couple free ".servebeer.com" records from them for many years now.  Their Windows updater is uglier (UI), but more stable than DynDNS' in my experience. :)